# CSS styling not applying to class

Tags: html, css, web, frontend, e-commerce

I'm trying to build an ecommerce website by watching a YouTube video. I am stuck at apply CSS style to some classes. I have given my html CSS code below. In that from the class "**#product1 .pro.des{** "onwards CSS styling is not applying to its content.on #product1 .pro.des{ element in CSS I tried to align text to start but it is not reflecting. Not only that but also the styling of other elements which comes after **"#product1 .pro.des{"** also are not working.   Hope someone will resolve this?

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Slab&family=Spartan:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap');

*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Spartan' sans-serif;
}

h1{
    font-size: 50PX;
    line-height: 64px;
    color: #222;

}

h2{
    font-size: 46PX;
    line-height: 54px;
    color: #222;

}

h4{
    font-size: 20PX;
    color: #222;

}

h6{
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 12px
}



p{
    font-size: 16PX;
    color: #465b52;
    margin: 15px 0 20px 0;

}

.section-p1{
    padding: 40px 80px;

}

.section-p1{
    margin: 40px 0;

}

body{
    width: 100%;
}


/*header start*/

#header{

    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between ;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 20px 80px;
    background-color: #e3e6f3;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 15p rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
    z-index: 999;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;

}

#navbar{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

#navbar li{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0 20px;
    position: relative;
}

#navbar li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #1a1a1a;
    transition: 0.3s ease;
}

#navbar li a:hover,
#navbar li a.active{
    color: #088178;
}

#navbar li a.active::after,
#navbar li a:hover::after{
    content: "";
    width: 30%;
    height: 2px;
    background: #088178;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -4px;
    left: 20px;
}

#hero{
    background-image: url("img/hero4.png");
    height: 90vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-position: top 25 right 0;
    background-size: cover;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content: center;
}

#hero h4{
    padding-bottom: 15px;

}

#hero h1{
    color: #088178;
}

#hero button{

    background-image: url(img/button.png);
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #088178;
    border:0;
    padding: 14px 80px 14px  65px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 15px;
}

#feature{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#feature .fe-box{
    width: 180px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 25px 15px;
    box-shadow: 20px 20px 34px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03);
    border: 1px solid #cce7d0;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin: 15px 0;
}

#feature .fe-box:hover{
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 34px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03);
}

#feature .fe-box h6{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 9px 8px 6px 8px;
    line-height: 1;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #088178;
    background-color: #fddde4;
}

#feature .fe-box img{
        width: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 10px;

    



}

#product1{
    text-align: center;
}

#product1 .pro{
    width: 23%;
    min-width: 250px;
    padding: 10px 12px;
    border: 1px solid #cce7d0;
    border-radius: 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: 20px 20px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02);
    margin: 15px 0;
}


#product1 .pro img{
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

#product1 .pro.des{
    text-align: start;
    padding: 10px 0;
}


#product1.pro.des span{
    color: #606063;
    font-size: 50px;

}

#product1 .pro.des h5{
    padding-top: 7px;
    color: #1a1a1a;
    font-size: 14px;
}

#product1 .pro.des i{
    font-size: 25px;
    color: rgb(241, 183, 25);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Ecommerce</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.4/css/all.css"/>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <section id="header">
    <a href="#"><img src="img/logo.png" class="logo"></a>
    <div>
        <ul id="navbar">
            <li><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a></l1>
            <li><a href="shop.html">Shop</a></l1>
            <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></l1>
            <li><a href="about.html">About</a></l1>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="cart.html"><i class="fa-solid fa-cart-arrow-down"></i></a></li>
            
        </ul>
    </div>
    </section>
    <section id="hero">
        <h4>Trade-in-offer</h4>
        <h2>Super Value Deals</h2>
        <h1>On all products</h1>
        <p>Save more with coupons & upto 70%off</p>
        <button>Shop Now</button>
    </section>
    <section id="feature" class="section-p1">
        <div class="fe-box">
            <img src="img/features/f1.png">
            <h6>Free Shipping</h6>
        </div>

        <div class="fe-box">
            <img src="img/features/f2.png">
            <h6>Online Order</h6>
        </div>

        <div class="fe-box">
            <img src="img/features/f3.png">
            <h6>Save Money</h6>
        </div>

        <div class="fe-box">
            <img src="img/features/f4.png">
            <h6>Promotions</h6>
        </div>

        <div class="fe-box">
            <img src="img/features/f5.png">
            <h6>Happy Sell</h6>
        </div>

        <div class="fe-box">
            <img src="img/features/f6.png">
            <h6>Support</h6>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section id="product1" class="section-p1">
        <h2>Featured Products</h2>
        <p>Summer Collections</p>
        <div class="pro-container">
            <div class="pro">
                <img src="img/products/f1.jpg">
                <div class="des">
                    <span>adidas</span>
                    <h5>Cartoon Astronaut Tshirt</h5>
                    <div class="star">
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    </div>
                    <h4>$78</h4>
                </div>
                <a href="#"><i class="fal fa-shopping-cart"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>


    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So for each element level you need a space. `#product1.pro.des span` should be `#product1 .pro .des span` since you want to target the element with id `product1`, that has a child with class `pro`, that has a child with class `des` that contains a span.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Should be `.pro > .des` or `.pro .des` (with a space) because `.des` is a child to `.pro`.

`.pro.des` would only be valid if those classes shared the same element.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Slab&family=Spartan:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Spartan' sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 50PX;
  line-height: 64px;
  color: #222;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 46PX;
  line-height: 54px;
  color: #222;
}

h4 {
  font-size: 20PX;
  color: #222;
}

h6 {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 12px
}

p {
  font-size: 16PX;
  color: #465b52;
  margin: 15px 0 20px 0;
}

.section-p1 {
  padding: 40px 80px;
}

.section-p1 {
  margin: 40px 0;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
}


/*header start*/

#header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 20px 80px;
  background-color: #e3e6f3;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 15p rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
  z-index: 999;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#navbar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#navbar li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0 20px;
  position: relative;
}

#navbar li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #1a1a1a;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
}

#navbar li a:hover,
#navbar li a.active {
  color: #088178;
}

#navbar li a.active::after,
#navbar li a:hover::after {
  content: "";
  width: 30%;
  height: 2px;
  background: #088178;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -4px;
  left: 20px;
}

#hero {
  background-image: url("img/hero4.png");
  height: 90vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-position: top 25 right 0;
  background-size: cover;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: center;
}

#hero h4 {
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

#hero h1 {
  color: #088178;
}

#hero button {
  background-image: url(img/button.png);
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #088178;
  border: 0;
  padding: 14px 80px 14px 65px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 15px;
}

#feature {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#feature .fe-box {
  width: 180px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 25px 15px;
  box-shadow: 20px 20px 34px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03);
  border: 1px solid #cce7d0;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 15px 0;
}

#feature .fe-box:hover {
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 34px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03);
}

#feature .fe-box h6 {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 9px 8px 6px 8px;
  line-height: 1;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #088178;
  background-color: #fddde4;
}

#feature .fe-box img {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#product1 {
  text-align: center;
}

#product1 .pro {
  width: 23%;
  min-width: 250px;
  padding: 10px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #cce7d0;
  border-radius: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 20px 20px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02);
  margin: 15px 0;
}

#product1 .pro img {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

#product1 .pro>.des {
  text-align: start;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

#product1.pro>.des span {
  color: #606063;
  font-size: 50px;
}

#product1 .pro >.des h5 {
  padding-top: 7px;
  color: #1a1a1a;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#product1 .pro >.des i {
  font-size: 25px;
  color: rgb(241, 183, 25);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Ecommerce</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.4/css/all.css" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <section id="header">
    <a href="#"><img src="img/logo.png" class="logo"></a>
    <div>
      <ul id="navbar">
        <li><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="shop.html">Shop</a></li>
        <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="cart.html"><i class="fa-solid fa-cart-arrow-down"></i></a></li>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section id="hero">
    <h4>Trade-in-offer</h4>
    <h2>Super Value Deals</h2>
    <h1>On all products</h1>
    <p>Save more with coupons & upto 70%off</p>
    <button>Shop Now</button>
  </section>
  <section id="feature" class="section-p1">
    <div class="fe-box">
      <img src="img/features/f1.png">
      <h6>Free Shipping</h6>
    </div>

    <div class="fe-box">
      <img src="img/features/f2.png">
      <h6>Online Order</h6>
    </div>

    <div class="fe-box">
      <img src="img/features/f3.png">
      <h6>Save Money</h6>
    </div>

    <div class="fe-box">
      <img src="img/features/f4.png">
      <h6>Promotions</h6>
    </div>

    <div class="fe-box">
      <img src="img/features/f5.png">
      <h6>Happy Sell</h6>
    </div>

    <div class="fe-box">
      <img src="img/features/f6.png">
      <h6>Support</h6>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section id="product1" class="section-p1">
    <h2>Featured Products</h2>
    <p>Summer Collections</p>
    <div class="pro-container">
      <div class="pro">
        <img src="img/products/f1.jpg">
        <div class="des">
          <span>adidas</span>
          <h5>Cartoon Astronaut Tshirt</h5>
          <div class="star">
            <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
            <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
            <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
            <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
            <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
          </div>
          <h4>$78</h4>
        </div>
        <a href="#"><i class="fal fa-shopping-cart"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>


  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**Side note:** markup was invalid due to missing closing `<li>` - you had `</ll>` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Add Spaces Between your selectors like:

```
#product1 .pro .des h5{
    padding-top: 7px;
    color: #1a1a1a;
    font-size: 14px;
}

#product1 .pro .des i{
    font-size: 25px;
    color: rgb(241, 183, 25);
}
```